# how to install and run rethinkdb in cpanel?

Tags: php, cpanel, rethinkdb

I'm having a hard time getting the RethinkDb server up in cpanel. I'm able to run it smoothly in my local machine using windows os.

I follow instruction listed here to somehow install it in cpanel.
https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/centos/

this is what exactly I typed in putty:

```
wget http://download.rethinkdb.com/dist/rethinkdb-2.3.6.tgz
tar xf rethinkdb-2.3.6.tgz
```

> I tried the above step as well as manually downloaded the .tgz file,
>   extracted it and the continued with below command to no avail.

```
cd rethinkdb-2.3.6
./configure --allow-fetch --dynamic jemalloc
make
sudo make install
```

It seems like the installation goes on and on.[image]

I waited until it complete installing and typed `rethinkdb` to start the server.
But it says undefined command.

Please guide me on how o install and run RethinkDb in cpanel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you are trying to install it from source and compile it since there are already created packages available for CentOS 6 & 7.

```
sudo wget http://download.rethinkdb.com/centos/7/`uname -m`/rethinkdb.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/rethinkdb.repo
sudo yum install rethinkdb
```

If it's CentOS 6, just then replace 7 with 6 after the CentOS repo.

Then just do a `service rethinkdb start` for CentOS 6.x or `systemctl start rethinkdb` for CentOS 7 and you should be good to go.

Comment: thank you so much. this just worked. But in order to start the rethinkdb, i just typed rethinkdb and it starts on centOs 7

Comment: How to do open the rethinkdb gui on port 8080 in cpanel?  It says listening to 127.0.0.1 on port 8080 but how do i access it?

Comment: You should start with --bind all option `rethinkdb --bind all`

Comment: I typed rethinkdb --bind all, after some time, i closed the rethinkdb and tried reconnecting. But it says rethinkdb_data is in use. maybe other instance using it. why could this happen as currently only my machine starts the server. i also tried to disconnect from internet just to end if any instance running but i keep getting the same message every time i type rethinkdb

Comment: Just be sure that the process is not running. You could issue a `service rethinkdb stop` or `systemctl stop rethinkdb`. Do a `ps ax | grep rethink` just to check if the process is not running. Probably, somehow, an instance of that process is already running or something else is listening on the rethinkdb port... This would be a good read: https://rethinkdb.com/docs/start-a-server/

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that I could help

Comment: can you see i you could me with this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299954/how-to-make-client-connect-to-ratchet-on-live-server

Comment: @oh its a different issue with ratchet connection on remote server.